# After clicking back an image popup make the page remain at the same position

Tags: html, css

After clicking back an image popup, how to make the browser go to the same position it was in before clicking?

After clicking the popup image the page goes to the top (red square in the example) and I would like the back position remain where the <kbd>Click</kbd> button is.

```css
* {overflow:visible;}


div {background:lightgray; height:200px; width:200px; margin: 0 auto 20px;}

div:first-child {background:red;}

.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: #747691;
    z-index: 510;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
   vertical-align: top;
}

.popup:target {
display: block;
-webkit-animation-name: fadein 0, 2s;
animation-name: fadein;
animation-duration: 0.2s;
background-color: rgb(116, 118, 145);
background-color: rgba(116, 118, 145, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<a href="#image">Click</a>

<div id="image" class="popup">
    <a href="#"><img id="popupImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with anchor `hrefs` (which is actually the reason for your issue), lets try to handle the click events using JS.

Adding onClick for button and image container div:

```html
 <button onclick="showImage()">Click</button>

    <div id="image" onclick="handleImageClick()">
      <img
        id="popupImage"
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg"
      />
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
    #image {
      display: none;
    }

    .popup {
      display: block !important;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      padding-top: 80px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      background: #747691;
      z-index: 510;
      opacity: 1;
      left: 0;
      vertical-align: top;

      -webkit-animation-name: fadein 0, 2s;
      animation-name: fadein;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      background-color: rgba(116, 118, 145, 0.7);
    }
```

**JS:**

```js
  <script>
    const element = document.getElementById("image");

    function showImage() {
      const element = document.getElementById("image");
      element.classList.add("popup");
    }

    function handleImageClick() {
      element.classList.remove("popup");
    }
  </script>
```